# how to remove special characters/numbers from cucumber console?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, gherkin

I'm new for Cucumber. While I'm writing a basic feature file I have used tables. and printed the same table values to see how they will display on console. But while printing the values I could see some special characters. What are they and how to remove them? any idea?
 I googled to get a solution, but couldn't make it. Can anyone please help me?

Here is my feature file:
    Feature: Addding two values
 Addding two values

```
Scenario: tesing sum values
  Given input and output
  When inputs <inputx> and <inputy> is given
 |22|33|
 |33|55|
 Then output must be <output>
 |55|
 |88|
```

And the below is my Ruby File

```
Given(/^input and output$/) do
  puts "Given block"
end

When(/^inputs <inputx> and <inputy> is given$/) do |table|
  # table is a Cucumber::Core::Ast::DataTable
  puts table
end

Then(/^output must be <output>$/) do |table|
   # table is a Cucumber::Core::Ast::DataTable
   puts table
end
```

And the below is the output on the console

```
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/) to get coloured output on Windows
C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber  --profile default
Using the default profile...
Feature: Addding two values
  Addding two values

  Scenario: tesing sum values
    [32mGiven input and output[0m
      [36mGiven block[0m
[32mWhen inputs <inputx> and <inputy> is given[0m
  [36m[0m
  [36m  | [32m    22[0m[0m |[0m [32m    33[0m[0m |[0m[0m
  [36m  | [32m    33[0m[0m |[0m [32m    55[0m[0m |[0m[0m
  | [36m22[0m[0m |[0m [36m33[0m[0m |[0m
  | [36m33[0m[0m |[0m [36m55[0m[0m |[0m
[32mThen output must be <output>[0m
  [36m[0m
  [36m  | [32m    55[0m[0m |[0m[0m
  [36m  | [32m    88[0m[0m |[0m[0m
  | [36m55[0m[0m |[0m
  | [36m88[0m[0m |[0m

1 scenario ([32m1 passed[0m)
3 steps ([32m3 passed[0m)
0m6.555s
```

Comment: Are you asking about the things like `[32m`? Those are a result of trying to output the report in colour. As the warning says, you will need to install ANSICON to get coloured output.

Comment: yes. But When I'm trying to collect the values from table and giving as input values into textbox in a browser, then also I'm able to see these special text like `[32m ` are entered along with the collected values.

Comment: @shiv:- use monochrome=true

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `--no-color` to your command line call or your default profile.

For example:

```
default: --no-source --no-color --format pretty
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because cucumber is trying to print the coloured output into the terminal, but your terminal is not able to do so. As a result these symbols are visible.
 To resolve this issue just add `monochrome = true` in the Runner (Step Definition) file where you are gluing this cucumber feature file.
Sample Code:

```
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/FeatureFiles/RegisterUser.feature", "src/test/resources/FeatureFiles/RegisterUserVerifyError.feature"}, 
glue = "com/assignment2/userreg/stepdefinations/",
tags = {"@multipleverify"}, monochrome = true, plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty"})
```

Comment: Hope your gets resolved, if not then do let me know in comments.